# What CI tools allow only failed stages to be re-run?

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

CircleCI lets you rerun only failed jobs.

Are there any other CI tools that let you do this?

Comment: Not sure if I got it.. But you can run failed and succeed builds on CircleCI, you can also do the same on Travis.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible on [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/blog/rerun-failed-pipeline-steps): [image: Screenshot showing option to rerun failed steps]